# "uninitialized constant Web" при старте приложения на heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Залил сайт на `heroku`.

В логах сервера вижу ошибки. C чем это может быть связано?

```
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616313+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in const_get': uninitialized constant Web (NameError)


2017-03-30T04:12:08.193864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-30T04:12:14.131527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19450 -e production`
2017-03-30T04:12:18.754437+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-30T04:12:18.749453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616313+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Web (NameError)
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616336+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:268:in `block in constantize'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616337+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616338+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616342+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616343+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/ckeditor-1a0db76ca95b/app/controllers/ckeditor/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616343+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616344+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:150:in `exclusive'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616346+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:476:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616346+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616348+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616347+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:475:in `block in eager_load!'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:473:in `eager_load!'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:354:in `eager_load!'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616350+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616352+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616355+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616361+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616361+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616369+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616369+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616370+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616371+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616372+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616390+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616391+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616391+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616394+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:282:in `start'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616409+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616409+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616410+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616411+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616443+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616443+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616445+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.616444+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-03-30T04:12:18.664647+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-03-30T04:12:18.664651+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:19450
2017-03-30T04:12:18.664652+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-30T04:12:18.664653+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Откуда берется `uninitialized constant Web`?

Вероятно, ваше приложение не может найти модуль `Web` в контроллерах. Такой модуль бывает в проекте, если вы выстраиваете иерархию контроллеров по статье: https://habrahabr.ru/post/136461/.

Я сам выстраиваю все свои контроллеры подобным образом. И, в частности - использую форки гемов [ckeditor](https://github.com/gambala/ckeditor) и [clearance](https://github.com/gambala/clearance), настроенные под `Web::ApplicationController`, вместо стандартного рельсового `ApplicationController`.

Возможно, вы используете в своем проекте один из моих форков? Если так, то вам нужно:

- Либо выстроить контроллеры в своем проекте с модулем `Web`;
- Либо исправить `Web::ApplicationController` на `ApplicationController` в инициализаторе используемого форка.

## 2. Почему ошибка всплыла на heroku, но не на localhost?

В `development` окружении рельса лениво загружает классы и модули проекта. Это хорошо, так как при изменении конкретного файла вы перезагружаете только его, не нужно перезапускать весь сервер, чтобы увидеть результат изменений.

При таком методе загрузки, если в каком-то файле или модуле содержится ошибка - вы не увидите сообщение о ней, пока не наткнетесь в проекте на это место. Например, пока не перейдете в проблемный роут.

В `production` окружении все классы и модули загружаются сразу при старте приложения. И все ошибки, в каких бы классах и модулях они не скрывались - всплывут сразу.